# Normal keyboard switcher for Gnome?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Is there any normal keyboard switcher for GNOME in Ubuntu?

"Normal" means:

1. Supports more than two languages. I.e. switches them not cyclically but with reordering with most popular on top.
2. Shows language indicator
3. Supports Chinese Pinyin input.
4. Doesn't steal focus on switching.
5. Supports any key combination, including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Before advise please ensure all requirements satisfied.

Various combination of standard settings and tweaks support all this with very low quality and various glitches.

Comment: May be it is time to try Ubuntu MATE with [IBus or Fcitx](https://ubuntu-mate.org/faq/roadmap/#complex-input-methods) in it?